# Does this Jquery plugin always return an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection) for photo face detection.  It works, but when there is no detectable face in a picture, the error function is not called.  The "complete" function is called instead.

I figure when it fails to detect a face, it returns no array, or returns undefined objects, or null, or something, so I've tried:

```
//also tried null this way
if(typeof coords[i].confidence === 'undefined') {
alert("you have little aptitude for programming."); 
}


if(coords instanceof Array) {

        alert("good job!!");
} else {
alert("not even close!!");
}


if(!(coords.length)) {
alert("you have a distorted perception of your own abilities.");
}


if (positionX > coords.length) {

alert(coords[i].confidence);
}
```

When a face is detected it displays the appropriate alerts, but when no face is detected, no alert is displayed.  It just calls the "complete" function.

Here is the script.  Let me know if I should provide more code.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#try').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            var coords = $('img').faceDetection({


                complete:function(img, coords) {
                    $this.text('Done!');

                },
                error:function(img, code, message) {
                    $this.text('error!');
                    alert('Error: '+message);
                }

            });



            for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {

//Here is where I have been putting those conditional statements.  

//This part, which appends a bordered div (#face) to the div containing the face pic, works fine.

                $('<div>', {
                    'class':'face',
                    'id':'face',
                    'css': {
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'left':     coords[i].positionX +'px',
                        'top':      coords[i].positionY +'px',
                        'width':    coords[i].width +'px',
                        'height':   coords[i].height    +'px'
                    }

                })
                .appendTo('#content');                               


            } 
        });


        return false;
    });
    </script>

<a href="#" id="try">TRY IT NOW!</a>               

<div id="content">
 <img src="pic.jpg" id="myPicture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps `complete` is invoked regardless of success or failure, similarly to the complete option for the `ajax` method in jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried logging `coords` in the console and seeing what its value is when there is no face recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`complete` is indeed invoked regardless of success. In case of a failure to detect any faces plugin returns empty array and that is why you don't see any alerts. Your `for` loop is not executed.

Comment: Right you are.  I could not understand why none of the conditions I set were calling those alerts on failure, but it turns out I was putting them in the wrong spot.  Now I have if(!(coords.length)) {
alert("fail");
} ABOVE the loop, and it works.  Thanks for your help!